# Edit profile page using laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

Whenever a user goes to mywebsite.com/profile I want a form to pre populate the values they've entered during the signup/registration flow. 
I was able to do that with my form here

```
<h1><b>Your Profile</b></h1>
<form method="POST" action="/profile/update">
    <div class="form-group hidden">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label for="email" class="control-label"><b>Name:</b></label>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Please enter your email here" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->name }}"/>

        <?php if ($errors->has('name')) :?>
        <span class="help-block">
            <strong>{{$errors->first('name')}}</strong>
        </span>
        <?php endif;?>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label for="email" class="control-label"><b>Email:</b></label>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Please enter your email here" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->email }}"/>

        <?php if ($errors->has('email')) :?>
        <span class="help-block">
            <strong>{{$errors->first('email')}}</strong>
        </span>
        <?php endif;?>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"> Submit </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

But now im running into the issue if the user just hits submit button without changing any fields, laravel's built in validations checks and gives me an error message of `The name has already been taken.` which is true. so im not sure how to handle this issue, but here is my controller below

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Update user profile & make backend push to DB
     * 
    **/

    public function index() {

        /**
         * fetching the user model
         **/
        $user = Auth::user();
        //var_dump($user);

        /**
         * Passing the user data to profile view
         */
        return view('profile', compact('user'));

    }

    public function update(Request $request) {
        /**
         * Validate request/input 
         **/
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255|unique:users',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        ]);

        /**
         * storing the input fields name & email in variable $input
         * type array
         **/
        $input = $request->only('name','email');

        /**
         * fetching the user model
         */
        $user = Auth::user();

        /**
         * Accessing the update method and passing in $input array of data
         **/
        $user->update($input);

        /**
         * after everything is done return them pack to /profile/ uri
         **/
        return back();
    }
}
```

and here is my routes file.

```
// only authenticated users
Route::group( ['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

    // practicing using forms for sending data to the DB & populating form fields with DB data
    Route::get('profile', 'ProfileController@index');
    Route::patch('profile/{id}', 'ProfileController@update');

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issue is due to unique validation rule. You can exclude the current user id by specifying unique validation rule. your code will be like this

```
 public function update(Request $request) {

  /**
     * fetching the user model
     */
    $user = Auth::user();


    /**
     * Validate request/input 
     **/
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255|unique:users,name,'.$user->id,
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users,email,'.$user->id,
    ]);

    /**
     * storing the input fields name & email in variable $input
     * type array
     **/
    $input = $request->only('name','email');



    /**
     * Accessing the update method and passing in $input array of data
     **/
    $user->update($input);

    /**
     * after everything is done return them pack to /profile/ uri
     **/
    return back();
}
```

here is laravel documentation link for this https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-unique

Comment: I have added the $user->id at end of validation rule to ignore that row which checking unique